# How to improve the performance of this query? It is taking more than a min?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have below query:
It is taking more than a minute...I need to improve the performance and bring it to less than 10 sec.

Appreciate your responses.

```
SELECT  
DISTINCT 
RP.RegionPerilID 
,RP.RegionName + ' ' + RP.ShortName AS RegionPerilName 
,LossLevelID
,LL.LossLvlName AS LossLevelName
FROM Axis_Accumulation.dbo.AIREventSet ES 
       JOIN Axis_Accumulation.dbo.vw_RegionPerils RP ON RP.RegionPerilId = ES.RegionPerilId 
       JOIN ART.LA.ELT_Blend ELT WITH (NOLOCK) ON ES.EventNum = ELT.EventNum AND ELT.Versionid = @versionId 
       JOIN dbo.LA_LossLevel LL ON ELT.LossLevelID = LL.LossLvlID AND LL.LosstypeId = 3 -- Line of Business
       ORDER By RegionPerilName
```

Comment: Do you have some execution plans? How many records are in each table separately?

Comment: Execution plans, table structure and indexes would be needed to offer much help. Meanwhile you might consider getting rid of that NOLOCK in there unless you are ok with mostly accurate data most of the time. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Comment: do you have any indexes on the tables that you can use in order for the query to run faster? make sure you're joining the tables properly.

Comment: Are all the table on the same server ?

Comment: Check what's in @versionId first. You may even want to hardcode it as a test. Also take a look at your view. If your view is slow, maybe select that into a table, add an index on it before doing your select.

Comment: @Rom Eh; yes. All the tables are on the same server

Answer (score 1):

You should try to create these indexes, if they not already exist :

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_AIREventSet ON Axis_Accumulation.dbo.AIREventSet
(
    RegionPerilID
)
INCLUDE
(
    EventNum
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_AIREventSet_EvenNum ON Axis_Accumulation.dbo.AIREventSet
(
    EventNum
)


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_vw_RegionPerils ON Axis_Accumulation.dbo.vw_RegionPerils
(
    RegionPerilID
)
INCLUDE
(
    RegionName,
    ShortName
)


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ELT_Blend ON ART.LA.ELT_Blend
(
    EventNum,
    Versionid,
)
INCLUDE
(
    LossLevelID
)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_ELT_Blend_LossLevelID ON ART.LA.ELT_Blend
(
    LossLevelID
)



CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_LA_LossLevel ON dbo.LA_LossLevel
(
    LossLvlID,
    LosstypeId
)
INCLUDE
(
    LossLvlName
)
```

If in the list below, the fields are unique, add the UNIQUE clause in the index definition.
The INCLUDE statement is important because it brings all the data by seeking one index.
Add the indexes one by one and check in the execution plan if they are used. If not you can delete it.

This last index should help for sorting the data !

```
CREATE CLUSTERED UNIQUE INDEX IX_AIREventSet_Clustered ON Axis_Accumulation.dbo.AIREventSet
(
    RegionName,
    ShortName,
    RegionPerilID,
    [YourTableId]
)
```

Comment: Hi Rom.... What is this [YourTableId] in the last Index? I don't have any Identity Column on this table.

Comment: If you have any Idenity Column, forget this field. You probably have to remove the unique clause too.